# In React how to add key prop to element passed as Object

Tags: reactjs, key

Approximately the code looks like this (CoffeeScript)

```
//In Parent component

render: () ->

  mycomp = <SomeComponent some_prop="something" />

  <ChildComponent passedComp = mycomp />


//In Child component

render: () ->

 someContent = [passedComp, <AnotherComp key={2} />]


 <div>
   {someContent}
 </div>
```

This generates a warning about missing key in the array in Child component.

The problem is how to add key={1} to passedComp in Child component. I can't do it in the render method of the Parent (alongside some_prop) because I can't know at this point what key should be. I need to add the key prop in the Child component - but here passedComp is already an object .

How can I modify passedComp to have a key?

- Updated:

I have

```
someContent = [<span key={1}>{passedComp}</span>, <AnotherComp key={2} />]
```

which gets rid of the React warning but the extra span breaks my (well react-bootstrap's) CSS. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do it if your component is already instantiated is to [clone your component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html) and add the `key` property

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That works - though the link you sent me has been updated and it can now be done with React.cloneElement, without an add-on. It's better than my solution - which would have entailed messy CSS to rescue the situation. For some reason some people don't like cloning elements - (which is one reason I didn't go down this route before) - but it looks fine to me. I don't know what the objection is that some people have to cloning instantiated objects. Thanks anyway; works fine for me (-:

Comment: Could you add an example?

Answer (score 19):

You can use a `React.Fragment` to add a key without breaking CSS and without the need to clone:

```
someContent = [<React.Fragment key={1}>{passedComp}</React.Fragment>, <AnotherComp key={2} />]
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else who stumbled across this:

Another potential way of injecting a Key is to add a dummy parent as follows:

With ES6 syntax:

```
class KeyedComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    // NOTE: This implementation assumes that your dummy component has
    // a single child.
    const child = React.Children.only(this.props.children);
    return child;
  }
}

// Use as follows:

// Stuff before...

render() {
  const someContent = [
    <KeyedComponent key="1">{passedComp}</KeyedComponent>,
    <AnotherComp key="2" />,
  ];
  // Stuff after...
}
```

Comment: You can now use <React.Fragment key={1}> as your dummy component